# 仮想マシン上のFedoraからshredコマンドを実行すると途中から書き込みエラーに

Tags: linux, command-line

932GiBの外付けHDD（sdb2）に対して、

`~$sudo shred -n 4 -z -v  /dev/sdb2`

を実行すると、30GiBぐらい書き込んだ辺りから、

`shred: /dev/sdb2: オフセット 32444973056 で書き込みエラーが発生しました: Input/output error`

が発生します。

5年前にUSBに対してshredコマンドを実行した際には、このようなエラーは起こらなかったのですが、今回は何度やっても30GiBぐらい書き込んだ辺りから弾かれてしまいます。何が原因なのか調べても満足がいく情報が見つからなかったので質問させていただきました。

追記）どうやら30GiBの乱数を書き込んだ辺りから、ゲストOS（ホストも？）へのマウントが解除されるようです。

ホストOS: Windows10
ゲストOS: Fedora29 GNOME

Comment: 参考までに仮想環境は何を使っていますか？また、あくまで「ディスクの消去」が目的であるならUSBブートなどを使用して物理マシンで直接試すのも一つの手なのかなと思いました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。昨日の日曜日にUSBからブートしたFedoraで無事ゼロ埋め等のフォーマットを完了することができました。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決したようで何よりです (仮想環境に由来した問題だったということでしょうかね)。私の回答は当てずっぽうに過ぎなかったので、もし良ければ解決に至った手順を「自己回答」として記録を残してみてください。ついでに何の仮想環境を使っていたのかも書いてもらえると他の人の参考になると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一応拙いまとめ方ですが、下方に記録しておきました。

Answer (score 1):

**あくまで私の環境（ThinkPad X280）での解決法なので参考程度に**

解決に至った次第ですが、ラップトップ（ThinkPad X280）のBIOSのブート起動に関する設定を[こちら](https://qiita.com/miy4/items/796c51813417cc90c77f)のQiitaの記事を元に変更。その後Fedora29のISOイメージを公式サイトからダウンロードし、イメージを「DD for Windows」でUSBメモリーに書き込み、ラップトップでブートしライブ起動。

外付けHDDをUSB3.0対応のポートに差し込み、ターミナルより`df -h`でマウントされていことを確認（"Sotozuke HDD"等分かりやすいドライブ名を指定すると確認が楽になる）。

確認後ターミナルより`shred -n 2 -z /dev/XXX`で目的のデバイスを指定し上書き作業を開始。

容量によって差はあるかと思いますが、900GiB以上ある記憶装置のフォーマット（乱数2回、ゼロ埋め1回）には1日掛かります。

最後になりましたが、使っている仮想環境はVirtualBox 5.2.22 r126460 (Qt5.6.2)です。

Answer (score 0):

該当ディスクの破損を疑いましょう。`fsck`などのチェックが通るか念のため確認してみてください。

私の場合はVirtualBox上のLinuxからホストOS(Windows10)に接続したSDカードに対して操作を行った際、破損したSDカードだと操作の途中でI/Oエラーが発生して接続状態も頻繁に解除されてしまうケースがありました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。昨日の日曜日にUSBブートしたFedoraを用いて最後までフォーマットを行うことができました。結果、乱数とゼロで埋めるのに一日かかりました。念の為ディスクをチェックしてみましたが、私の環境ではエラーは検出されませんでした。